# Receiving a weird error while using zipfile and I'm not sure why. Program seems fine

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-zipfile

Im receiving this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'file1.txt'

Here is my code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfx5E.png)

I am honestly clueless...
Here is code in text in case you want to mess with it:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipName = ZipFile(input('Enter zip file name: '), 'w')
fileName = ''

while fileName != 'quit':
    fileName = input('Enter file name to zip (enter quit to exit): ')
    zipName.write(fileName)

zipName.close()

x = input()
```

Comment: Where is the source file, in your question 'file1.txt'?

Comment: I just typed 'file1.txt' as the input for fileName, I think this would then create a new file called 'file1.txt'; however, the error then occurs. I dont have a path specified for the file because I assumed it would just add the new blank 'file1.txt' to the zip file.

Comment: Well, If 'file1.txt' doesn't exist ZipFile.write() won't work.

Comment: If you want to create zip from empty file, firstly you have to create it. What you can do is, if file doesn't exist create file, make a zip using that file then remove the source file.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh... I must have totally misunderstood .write() then... what method would I use to create 'file1.txt'?

Comment: Just empty one am I right?

Comment: Yup, just an empty file.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica it is for ZipFile() object creation. Not for ZipFile.write() method, check it again please. Also it means truncate and write a new file for zip file not source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parameter of `ZipFile.write()` should be file name which exist one. Create temp file and delete it after writing. Also your while loop has a small mistake in it's logic, after typing `'quit'` code runs for `'quit'` file.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os

zipName = ZipFile(input('Enter zip file name: '), 'w')
fileName = ''

while True:
    fileName = input('Enter file name to zip (enter quit to exit): ')
    if fileName == "quit":
        break
    open(fileName, 'w+').close()
    zipName.write(fileName)
    os.remove(fileName)
```